# Extract value by using function with parameter in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary containing both the title and the number of pages of a book. Here is the `dict`:

```
text = {
    1: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Boy Who Lived", "pages": "146"},
        2: {"ch.name": "The Vanishing Glass", "pages": "126"},
    },
    2: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Worst Birthday", "pages": "129"},
        2: {"ch.name": "Dobby's Warning", "pages": "125"},
    },
}
```

And this is my code:

```py
def stranger_binger(seasons,start,pages_left):
    num_pages_watched = 0

    for key1, value1 in seasons.items():
        for key2, value2 in value1.items():
            output = key1,key2,value2['ch.name'],value2['pages']
            output

    for key1, value1 in seasons.items():
        for key2, value2 in value1.items():
            pages_left = pages_left-int(value2['pages'])
            if start == start and pages_left > 0:
                pages_left
            if start == start and pages_left > 0:
                left = pages_left
                print(f"Watched Season {key1} Chapter {key2}: '{value2['ch.name']}', {pages_left} pages left !")
                num_pages_watched = num_pages_watched +1
            elif start == start and pages_left < 0:
                print(f"No more full Chapter today! Only {left} pages are left , but Season {key1} Chapter {key2}: '{value2['ch.name']}' has {value2['pages']}pages.")
                print(f"{num_pages_watched} chapter(s) watched today.")
                return start

stranger_binger({
    1: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Boy Who Lived", "pages": "146"},
        2: {"ch.name": "The Vanishing Glass", "pages": "126"},
    },
    2: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Worst Birthday", "pages": "129"},
        2: {"ch.name": "Dobby's Warning", "pages": "125"},
    },
},(1,2),300)
```

This is the result:

```
Watched Season 1 Chapter 1: 'The Boy Who Lived', 154 pages left !
Watched Season 1 Chapter 2: 'The Vanishing Glass', 28 pages left !
No more full Chapter today! Only 28 pages are left , but Season 2 Chapter 1: 'The Worst Birthday' has 129pages.
2 chapter(s) watched today.
```

But I want the result start as 'start' parameter is `(1,2)` and print:

```
Watched Season 1 Chapter 2: 'The Vanishing Glass', 174 pages left !
Watched Season 2 Chapter 1: 'The Vanishing Glass', 45 pages left !
No more full Chapter today! Only 45 pages are left , but Season 2 Chapter 2: 'Dobby's Warning' has 125pages.
2 chapter(s) watched today.
```

Comment: Your `start` parameter has no effect on your function. Please explain what you mean by this line: `if start == start and pages_left > 0:`

Comment: I want ```start``` parameter start at (1,2)

Comment: Yes, you provided the value `(1,2)` for the `start` parameter, but `start` has no effect on your function. What is it meant to do? What would a different value do?

Comment: So how can I do to start the function at ```(1,2)```?

Comment: What does `(1,2)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could restructure slightly like this:

```
def stranger_binger(seasons, start, pages_left):
    num_pages_watched = 0
    started = False # added to determine if we've reached the start point yet
    for season, chapters in seasons.items():
        for chapter, info in chapters.items():
            if not started:
                if start == (season, chapter):
                    started = True
                else:
                    continue # continue to the next chapter until the start point is reached
            pages = int(info['pages'])
            if pages > pages_left:
                print(f"No more full Chapter today! Only {pages_left} pages are left , but Season {season} Chapter {chapter}: '{info['ch.name']}' has {pages} pages.")
                return start
            else:
                pages_left -= pages
                print(f"Watched Season {season} Chapter {chapter}: '{info['ch.name']}', {pages_left} pages left !")
                num_pages_watched = num_pages_watched + 1
                

stranger_binger({
    1: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Boy Who Lived", "pages": "146"},
        2: {"ch.name": "The Vanishing Glass", "pages": "126"},
    },
    2: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Worst Birthday", "pages": "129"},
        2: {"ch.name": "Dobby's Warning", "pages": "125"},
    },
},(1,2),300)
```

Descriptive variable names help you piece together the logic better.

I've added a few comments to highlight the important sections.

Output:

```
Watched Season 1 Chapter 2: 'The Vanishing Glass', 174 pages left !
Watched Season 2 Chapter 1: 'The Worst Birthday', 45 pages left !
No more full Chapter today! Only 45 pages are left , but Season 2 Chapter 2: 'Dobby's Warning' has 125 pages.
```

It may be helpful to `return (season, chapter)` so you can start again at the point you left off.

Comment: But aren't you ignoring the `start` parameter?

Comment: No. See `if start == (season, chapter):`. The start is the position of the starting point to watch/read. Basically, start at Season 1, Chapter 2. It just hits `continue`s until the correct key pair is reached.

Comment: Ok, yes. Sorry, I misread that bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. May I know what is ``` If not started``` meaning?

Comment: @Talkthattalk sure. `started` is just a flag I used to tell if you're at the point to start reading. If `started` is `False`, that means you need to check if you're at the start point before you deplete your pages. If you're not at the start point, `continue` skips the lower section and "continues" to the next loop or chapter.